# error on colour values

Tags: android, eclipse

My application is calling an image from gallery and when you click on a place of the image, it  voice out the colour. I'm facing a problem; I'm using a these codes to get the colour value for each place on the image. The funny thing is, it detects the colour values correctly (i.e. for red it shows r=255, g=0, b=0) but when it comes to saying the colour name (which I used 'TextToSpeech' for saying the colour name), it mostly says" The colour is black (unless you click on white, which it says Colour is white.
Here is my code:

```
    if  ((Color.red(pixel) & Color.blue(pixel) & Color.green(pixel))> 220) {
        if(TTSInitialized){
            mTts.speak("Color is White", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        textViewCol.setText("Color is White.");
        return true;}

    if  ((Color.red(pixel) & Color.blue(pixel) & Color.green(pixel)) < 10) {
        if(TTSInitialized){
            mTts.speak("Color is Black", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        textViewCol.setText("Color is Black.");
        return true;}

    if  ((Color.red(pixel) & Color.blue(pixel)) > 120) {
        if(TTSInitialized){
            mTts.speak("Color is Purple", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        }
        textViewCol.setText("Color is Purple.");
    return true;}

    if  (Color.red(pixel) > (Color.blue(pixel) & Color.green(pixel))) {
        if(TTSInitialized){
            mTts.speak("Color is  RED", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        textViewCol.setText("Color is  Red.");
        return true;}
```

My application has Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Purple, Cyan, Black and White. Now the question is: Is the way I'm writing the code correct? if not, what do you suggest? And Why is it always saying Black, no matter you click on red, blue or any other colour?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were off a bit on the second check.  I think  you wanted this:

```
  if  ((Color.red(pixel) | Color.blue(pixel) | Color.green(pixel)) < 10) {
        if(TTSInitialized){
            mTts.speak("Color is Black", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        textViewCol.setText("Color is Black.");
        return true;
   }
```

that way you are OR'ing the values and getting the cumulative amount, instead of the minimum of the three values.

For example:

3 | 7 | 255 = 255

but 3 & 7 & 255 = 3

Also, with your all of your checks, I'd probably redo them.  & is really checking more of a bitmask than an intensity.  With &, you only get the bits that are set in each number.

for white, I'd use:

```
if  (Color.red(pixel) > 220 && Color.blue(pixel) > 220 && Color.green(pixel) > 220)
```

for purple:

```
if  (Color.red(pixel) > 120  && Color.blue(pixel) > 120)
```

for red:

```
if  (Color.red(pixel) > (Color.blue(pixel) | Color.green(pixel)))
```

Comment: I'll drink to you!
Thanks, it worked... now I have to see if it works as good as this on real phone or not. Last time, it was working fine in emulator but once I export the signed application and installed it on my phone, there was no sound!!!!
Do you have any suggestion for that by any chance?!

Comment: I am a graphics guy... not so much with audio.  You should ask an audio question on here.  I'm sure someone will answer it.